# Cryptographically validating contents of zip file

Tags: c#, digital-signature, signing

I am looking to package up and distribute a zip file, and I would like to know the best way to be sure the contents of the zip have not been altered in any way.

Not all the files in the zip will be mine - some will be third party binaries, so digitally signing the files is only a partial solution. Encrypting the zip is not an option because the secret will be discoverable - it needs to be unencrypted at its destination. Publishing a hash is an option but not the ideal one because a separate piece of information is required to validate the zip (not to mention that it isn't secure - if someone can own your distribution server they can also change the hash that is published).

An approach similar to how a ClickOnce package is cryptographically signed would be ideal (I have a code signing certificate I can use for this). Can I use mage.exe to generate an arbitrary manifest which is shipped in the zip (therefore the zip itself doesn't have to be secure and altering/adding/removing files will break the crypto signature)? If so, how do I (programmatically) validate the signature at the destination?

Answer (score 1):

There exist several different approaches.

1. PKWare offers SecureZIP application that lets you sign the ZIP file using the format defined in PKWare's APPNote (normative reference for ZIP file format). Some third-party applications and libraries can verify such signatures. Signing, however, can be done only using SecureZIP (this is a licensing restriction).
2. You can use ["open packaging convention"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Packaging_Conventions) to sign contents of ZIP archives.
3. You can use [ASiC](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/102900_102999/102918/01.01.01_60/ts_102918v010101p.pdf) format, new european format for signing of data in ZIP files.

All of the above options are supported by our SecureBlackbox product. Unfortunately I don't have information about their support by other software.